# Why are the third and fourth parameters of child.layout() prefixed?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-viewgroup

```
child.layout(x, y, x + child.getMeasuredWidth(), y + child.getMeasuredHeight());
```

As you can see from the code snippet above, the third parameter is prefixed with `x` and the fourth with `y`. Aren't `x` and `y` co-ordinates? What's the difference if I do this?

```
child.layout(x, y, child.getMeasuredWidth(),child.getMeasuredHeight());
```

Comment: The `layout()` method takes `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` arguments; basically, the coordinates for each side. Your example is passing `left`, `top`, `width`, and `height`. See the difference?

Comment: ‍♂️. Yeah, I do. Thanks.